# How to get previous message's text with a Telegram bot?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I am building a reply keyboard oriented bot using java and I need it to treat differently two scenarios in which the latest message's text is the same based on the text of the previous message. How can I get or store the text of the previous message as a public variable?

My conceptual modelling is as follows:

I have a large If-Else-If statement where the condition for each If block goes along the lines of `if(update.hasMessage() && messageText.equals("aaa"))` where "aaa" is some text that appears on a reply keyboard that popped up for the user earlier (since the keyboard buttons send the string on them as text and there is no option for a button press event in Telegram bot's api). messageText is defined as update.getMessage().getText().

I want the code to treat differently two scenarios in which messageText is the same based on the message that came before it. `if(update.hasMessage() && messageText.equals("aaa") && previousMessage.equals("bbb")) { } else if(update.hasMessage() && messageText.equals("aaa") && previousMessage.equals("ccc")){}`. How can I store the previous message without it getting updated upon a new message recieved?

Comment: Hi, why you don't use standard existing design patterns to control the state of users? For example, state pattern?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of patterns that you can use for controlling the state of users, But as a simple trick what I did in my telegram bot, you can generate next message data based on current message response. For example when user send "aaa" as the first message response, and you want to generate the next message you can add first message data to it's callback like this: "aaa,bbb" and when calls the api you notice that previous message was "aaa" by splitting the callback data with ','.

Comment: Hey. Can you please add an example? I mean are you discussing the message that you already received? Let say, I want to know the message that user sent is an answer to what message